# error cannot find view MVC4 c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i made this protal which worked fine, however when i realised this to the live website i got an error saying:

```
   Message: The view 'EditRole' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/EditRole.aspx  
 ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/EditRole.ascx ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditRole.aspx   
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditRole.ascx ~/Views/Users/EditRole.aspx ~/Views/Users/EditRole.ascx 
~/Views/Shared/EditRole.aspx ~/Views/Shared/EditRole.ascx ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/EditRole.cshtml 
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/EditRole.vbhtml ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditRole.cshtml 
~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditRole.vbhtml ~/Views/Users/EditRole.cshtml 
~/Views/Users/EditRole.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/EditRole.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/EditRole.vbhtml
Source: System.Web.Mvc
```

my cshtml code:

```
     <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Roles", "EditRole", "Users", new { roleId = r.RoleID }, new { @class = "action" }) </td>
```

Controller:

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditRole(Role role)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {         
            }
            return RedirectToAction("EditRole");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EditRole");
        }
    }
```

Problem is, when i run it on local host everything works! but when i put it on the server its giving me the error.

Any ideas?

one thing iv noticed in the error is, it says:

```
 The following locations were searched: ~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/EditRole.aspx
```

But it should be, EditRole.cshtml
But am not sure why its saying EditRole.aspx when there is no such thing.

Comment: Maybe an obvious thought but, have you checked the mentioned locations on the server to see if the views are actually there?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using on the server?

Comment: IIS 7. check location how. i dont understand because its been working fine in local host...

Comment: The error message says location**s**. The view engine(s) looked in all of the places in that list.

Comment: the actual link is :/Admin/Users/EditRole?roleId=1.   but main problem is how come its working in local host!

Comment: If it works locally but doesn't work on the server, make sure that the view was deployed to the server.

Comment: Aspx is the default view engine and it will look there first and then for your razor views. add the following code to the Global.asax Application_start method "ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());". Sounds like you have not included the view in your project as Brian said.